# How can I set the screen to turn off during a video?

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, video, gallery, sleep

I want to set the screen to turn off during a video from the gallery if there are something about 30 seconds without any touch,
How can I do that?
Is root necessary?

My android version is 9.0.

Comment: I believe you can do it through an adb shell without root. However, the way I know of you have to manually input the commands. I do not know how to set a timer. I believe the power button is keyevent 26. Try opening an elevated command prompt and with adb throw the command: `adb shell input keyevent 26` that should press the power button and hopefully turn of the screen. Then throw the command again to turn it on.

Comment: So you mean that I need to try that line of code to check if the power button is ```keyevent 26```?

Comment: Yes, it might work depending on your android version. You need to invoke an `adb shell` with the shell send the command `input keyevent 26` which should simulate a power button push shutting of the screen.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it might work depending on your android version"?

Comment: My android version is 9.0, would it cause different code?

Comment: "As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's (input method editor) discretion

In general, the framework cannot guarantee that the key events it delivers to a view always constitute complete key sequences since some events may be dropped or modified by containing views before they are delivered"

Yep, it still is 26

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_POWER